# Как сделать из изображения 1x1 > 4x3?

Tags: css

Видел такое решение в некоторых интернет-магазинах: для изображения добавляется контейнер, при вставке изображения в контейнер оно растягивается по всей высоте контейнера и выравнивается по центру, а ширина обрезается контейнером. В итоге получается из 1x1 > 3x4.

Я использую CSS Framework Bulma. По умолчанию у нас уже есть [контейнер для изображения](https://bulma.io/documentation/elements/image/) сохраняющий нужное нам соотношение сторон (3x4). Однако, если я добавлю изображение 1x1, то оно просто растянется под размер контейнера. Как сделать центрирование изображения и обрезать по краям?

```
<figure class="image is-3by4">
    <img src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/480x640.png">
</figure>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Вариант №1**
Попробуйте для изображения добавить следующие правила ([93% браузеров поддерживает этот вариант](https://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit)):

```
.image-1{
   object-fit: cover;
   object-position: center;
   width:100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```

**Вариант №2**
Вместо тега `img` использовать `div` + `background-size` (поддержка 96,5%+ браузеров)

**Вариант №3**
  Для родителя `figure` использовать `overflow: hidden;`, для изображения `height:100%; transform:translate(-50%, -50%);` + vendor-prefix (-moz, -webkit, -o, -ms) (поддержка 97,37%+ браузеров)

Comment: Насколько это кроссбраузерное решение? В основном на сайт заходят с мобильных устройств, при чем не новых.

Comment: @РодионПоляков, изменил ответ